# Select from parent table where all rows of child table meets a certain value

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables :

Companies :
id , domain , ....

Contacts:
id, company_domain, validated, ....

Is there a way to get all the companies that have ALL their contacts validated = 1 with a single query ?

Comment: Count the number of contacts and the number of validated contacts. If those are the same, then all the contacts are validated.

Comment: Or get all the companies that *don't* have any non-validated contacts.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [mcve]. For further information, please see [ask], and take the [tour] :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the key between companies and contacts is company_domain how about something like this...

```
    select companies.id,companies.domain, count(*) as contact_count, 
    sum(contacts.validated) as validated_sum 
    from companies join contacts on contacts.company_domain = companies.domain 
    group by companies.id, companies.domain
    having contact_count = validated_sum;
```

not sure how efficient the having clause will be on this